# grocery crud insert duplicate data multiple time

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Hi I am using Grocery CRUD with HMVC and I am facing some strange problem with that.

```
class Source extends MX_Controller
{

    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
            try{
                $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

                $crud->set_theme('datatables');
                $crud->set_table('source');
                $crud->set_subject('Source');

                $output = $crud->render();
                $data['css_files'] = $output->css_files;
                $data['js_files'] = $output->js_files;
                $data['output'] = $output->output;

                $this->template->title('Source')
                    ->set_layout('default')
                    ->build('example', $data );

            }catch(Exception $e){
                show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
            }
    }
}
```

And in source table I have only one column "name" and other is id with auto increment and primary key.

When I add or insert data, it add multiple data in table some time 3 or 4 times  duplicate data.

I am also using template library.

This is strange issue I am facing first time with this Grocery Crud, can any one help me out to solve this.

Comment: if you are using a "view file" and a "header file", checked you are not duplicating the php code in both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have same issue with grocerycrud data get inserted multiple time, and I solve this issue by adding following code to the js file.

I was using datatable theme and in that the file was
grocery_crud\themes\datatables\js\datatables-add.js

```
$('#save-and-go-back-button').click(function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        save_and_close = true;

        $('#crudForm').trigger('submit');
});

$('#crudForm').submit(function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            url: validation_url,
.......
```

we need to add "event.stopImmediatePropagation();" after the click and submit events.

This will help to stop multiple dulplicate insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, Controller:

```
    class Source extends MX_Controller
    {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index(){
            try{
                $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

                $crud->set_theme('datatables');
                $crud->set_table('source');
                $crud->set_subject('Source');

                //edit the id of source table as it's on your table..
                $crud->set_primary_key('id', 'source');

                //set the columns you want
                $crud->columns(
                    'id',
                    'name'
                );

                //how do you want to display them in the frontend
                $crud->display_as('id', 'id');
                $crud->display_as('name', 'name');

                $table = $crud->render();
                $this->_table_output($table);

            }catch(Exception $e){
                show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Additional function needed:

```
private function _table_output($output = null)
{
    //load reservations table
    $this->load->view('yourviewfile', $output);
}
```

View:

```
<?php
foreach($output['css_files'] as $file): ?>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($output['js_files'] as $file): ?>
    <script src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div>
    <?php echo $output['output']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: same problem with this also.

Comment: Try the new code i just edited. don't forget to edit where i left comments

Comment: @user2293790 have you got teamviewer?

Comment: I will be back after some, we will to than teamviewer

Answer (score 0):

there is a reason to get duplicated rows listed when display the grocery crud:
- IF YOU HAVE A RELATION function (set_relation_n_n) between a **view** and **table** then you have to be sure that the view have **unique** ID column  (**with no Duplicated values**) else you will got the duplicated row, the solution is to use:
 $crud->set_primary_key('id', '*viewname*');
put this line before relation function.